# How to redirect to another page and display flash message in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and nextjs,Right now i am submitting form via axios(Api)
Form is submitting successfully but after submitting form i want page should change(should display Allblogs.js,something like redirect) and display flash message "Your form submitting successfully"
How can we do this ? Here is my current code

```
const response = await axios({
              method: "post",
              url: "https://diggdevelopment.com/blackstallion_new/api/testinfo_new/",
              data: formData,
              headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
                      }).then(function (response) {
                        alert('Form submitting successfully');
                        //should redirect and display flash messag on another page
                
            }).catch(function (error) {
               alert('respone is '+ error);
            });
```

Comment: use navigate from react navigate("/") your path inside the navigate. try and revert back .

Comment: are you using react router ?

Comment: @ShilpeSaxena and what about flash message ?

Comment: @monim not yet , kindly explain your point

Comment: slash means your path you have to write you path location there like I need to redirect my page t home page so I will write like navigate("/home");

Comment: @ShilpeSaxena i understand your point but i want to know that how can we display flash message after redirection ?

Comment: See I don't know how you have handled your next page in which you want your msg to be flashed and displayed. So, for now, suppose make another page(your redirecting page) and write your message and when you navigate it to that page it will render your message of that particular page.

Comment: @ShilpeSaxena let me explain , I have 2 pages ( first one is Add blog and second is Show Blogs) and i am working "Addblog" page and want whenever user record submit ( response is success) then should redirect to "show blogs" page in that page message should display "your data submitted successfully" Thats It

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push new path with query and in new page see if query exists so show the alert

```
    const router = useRouter();
const response = await axios({
              method: "post",
              url: "https://diggdevelopment.com/blackstallion_new/api/testinfo_new/",
              data: formData,
              headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
                      }).then(function (response) {
                        router.push({ pathname: "/home", query: { form: "submited" } });
                
            })
             .catch(function (error) {
               alert('respone is '+ error);
            });
```

and in home page :

```
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
 if(router.query?.form === 'submited')
  {
    alert('Form submitting successfully');
    router.replace('/home', undefined, { shallow: true });
  }

}, [router.query]);
```

Comment: whenever i submit form then its redirect to home page but with url showing "?form=submited"

Comment: And alert is also not wokring in home page

Comment: that's what query param is, in react you can pass state so no change would be in url but in next you cannot

Comment: could you please console.log router.query   in home page ? (to see what is in that)

Comment: its working but if user enter url manually ( url + ?form=submited ) then flash message will display, Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: yes, if you replace route it will remove query param and it wont redirect because it's already has the  page 
let me update my answer

Comment: update my answer, now it will remove query params from url , Iet me know if it works as expected

Comment: showing me error " SecurityError: The operation is insecure. "

Comment: sry, I forgot to add bracket for my condition, could please check this out again ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're posting data to an external site and want to redirect back to your site, you could just add a "then" and redirect.

```
const router = useRouter();
const response = await axios({
              method: "post",
              url: "https://diggdevelopment.com/blackstallion_new/api/testinfo_new/",
              data: formData,
              headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
                      }).then(function (response) {
                        alert('Form submitting successfully');
                        //should redirect and display flash messag on another page
                
            }).then(() => router.push('/home'))
    .catch(function (error) {
               alert('respone is '+ error);
            });
```

If this is for an internal link, you can use [forms and API routes.](https://nextjs.org/docs/guides/building-forms)

Comment: Okay with your code i will redirect to another page(home) but what about flash message ? (with condiiton ...if blog added successfully only then flash message should display)

Comment: You could add a model on the home page that is triggered by a query value such as `router.push({
          pathname: '/home',
          query: { success: true },
        })`

Comment: understand but how can i use condition ( if blog added only then flash message/modal should display)

Comment: You can add that logic to your `.then` function and `useState` to show the modal. In your question you asked about redirecting to a different page specifically, but it sounds like you may just want to show a modal?

Answer (score 0):

```
const response = await axios({
              method: "post",
              url: "https://diggdevelopment.com/blackstallion_new/api/testinfo_new/",
              data: formData,
              headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
                      }).then(function (response) {
                        alert('Form submitting successfully');
                        //should redirect and display flash messag on another page                      
                          navigate("/");
                          alert("Your flashing message will be displayed on your rendered page")

                
            }).catch(function (error) {
               alert('respone is '+ error);
            });
```

I'm saying this. try to do your flashing implementation on your won that how you want it to be flashed your message.